# How to use a query result as a variable ? Hasura Flutter

Tags: flutter, graphql, hasura

I am using Hasura with my Flutter Application..

I have 2 tables: `tasks` and `categories`

`tasks` comprises of `id`, `task_name`, `category_id`, `status`.
`category` comprises of `id`, `category_name`, `user_id`, `color`.

What I want to do is get the name of the category that the task belongs to using the category_id

What I thought of is:

```
query getTasks($user_id: String!) {
  tasks(where: user_id: {_eq: $user_id}}, order_by: {created_at: desc}) {
    category_id
    name
  }
  category_by_pk(id: tasks['category_id']){
    name
  }
}
```

The part that is `tasks['category_id']` being passed as a query variablele is giving an error

Any idea how can I do this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tracked a relationship in Hasura between `tasks` and `categories`? Normally with GraphQL you would just traverse the relationship to get information about the related entity:

```
query getTasks($user_id: String!) {
  tasks(where: user_id: {_eq: $user_id}}, order_by: {created_at: desc}) {
    name
    category { // Just follow the relationship
      id
      name
    }
  }
}
```